# How to enable the gradle daemon in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-daemon

While it's possible to run gradle from the CLI:

```
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/gradle$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/gradle$ clear;gradle clean build;java -jar build/libs/gradle.jar 

:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.674 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
hello world
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/gradle$
```

How do specify to use the daemon?

build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}


jar  {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.bounceme.mordor.gradle.HelloWorld'
    }
}
```

Netbeans doesn't create a gradle.properties file.  I added such a file:

```
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/gradle$ cat gradle.properties 
org.gradle.daemon=true
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/gradle$
```

So that the daemon is enabled.  Is this the correct Netbeans way?  Or, will this cause problems down the road?  Seems odd that the [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support) didn't include this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans, just like other IDEs, uses the [Gradle Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html) to execute builds internally. It just so happens that the Tooling API *always* uses the [Gradle Daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html), so no configuration is needed for Netbeans itself.